# Method of class ignored by code

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have such a situation that, at some point in my program, I create a pointer with new. Then I try to use some method of the allocated pointer class and the code just get ignored. No crash but when I run test after, it's like nothing happened:

Here is the code, the `setAge` function is the one getting ignored:

```
g2o::EdgeLinkXY_malcolm* linkObservation = new g2o::EdgeLinkXY_malcolm;

bool outout = false;
std::cout << "Bool" << outout << std::endl;
outout = linkObservation->interface.setAge(_age_start_value);
std::cout << "Bool" << outout << std::endl;
assert(outout == 1);
std::cout << "Age set" << std::endl;
assert(linkObservation->interface.manuallySetAge() == true);
```

EdgeLinkXY_malcolm possess an attribute named `interface` that is like this:

```
class G2O_TYPES_SLAM2D_API EdgeInterfaceMalcolm
{
  protected:
   bool _flag_set_age;
  public:
   g2o::SE2 _malcolm_original_value;
  double _malcolm_age;

//       EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
   EdgeInterfaceMalcolm() : _flag_set_age(false), _malcolm_age(1){};

 virtual g2o::SE2 getOriginalValue(){return _malcolm_original_value;}
 virtual void setOriginalValue(const g2o::SE2& orig_val){_malcolm_original_value = orig_val;}
 virtual bool manuallySetAge(){return _flag_set_age;}
 virtual double getAge(){return _malcolm_age;}
 virtual bool setAge(double a){
  std::cout << "Setting the age" << std::endl;
  _flag_set_age = true;  
  assert(_flag_set_age == true); 
  _malcolm_age = a; 
  return _flag_set_age;
}

};
```

And here is the edge_link:

```
class G2O_TYPES_SLAM2D_API EdgeLinkXY_malcolm : public EdgeSE2PointXY
{
  public:
    EdgeInterfaceMalcolm interface;
//       EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW;
   EdgeLinkXY_malcolm();
}
```

And it's constructor:

```
EdgeLinkXY_malcolm::EdgeLinkXY_malcolm() :
    EdgeSE2PointXY()
  {
  }
```

I have a test file where I try the function written above and it works fine, all the tests are passing. It just happen that sometime when running the real program, `setAge()` get ignored. The print inside the function is not even printed on the terminal. The variable `outout` seems also to be ignored by the assert, as `assert(outout == 1)` doesn't stop even though outout can be equal to another value. This is the part where my code stops:

```
Bool0
Bool45
Age set
acg_node_rviz_full: /home/malcolm/ros_catkin_ws/indigo_ws/src/auto_complete_graph/src/ACG.cpp:258: g2o::EdgeLinkXY_malcolm* AASS::acg::AutoCompleteGraph::addLinkBetweenMaps(const Vector2D&, g2o::VertexSE2Prior*, g2o::VertexPointXY*): Assertion `linkObservation->interface.manuallySetAge() == true' failed.
```

I have no clue why this does not work and I am very confused as to what did I do wrong so that c++ code can be ignored like this without crashing?

Comment: What is `EdgeInterfaceMalcolm`? Is it a virtual base-class? Is `interface` supposed to be "pointing" to a child-class of `EdgeInterfaceMalcolm`?

Comment: Just realised I copy-pasted the wrong code. `EdgeinterfaceMalcolm` is just a class that I put as attribute in all my edges. It's not a virtual-base class. `interface` is the name of the attribute in my edge which is a `EdgeinterfaceMalcolm`

Comment: When a thing happens only sometimes, it's usually a sign that something, somewhere is undefined.

Comment: The thing is, if `EdgeinterfaceMalcolm` is not supposed to be a base-class, why does it have virtual functions? Can you please show us the `EdgeLinkXY_malcolm` constructor? How are you initializing `EdgeLinkXY_malcolm::interface`?

Comment: I don't think they need to be virtual functions, you're right. Ì simply use the default constructor to initialize `interface`. I'm adding the constructor of `EdgeLinkXY_malcolm`to the post but there is nothing in it.

Comment: can you try to use a line-by-line debugger to see what's happening? @Malc

Comment: I probably could but I don't really know how to use a debugger :(. I'm sorry, guess it will be time for me to pick it up